# How to export multiple functions as aliases in ES6

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I want to export multiple functions as aliases in ES6.

I exported it like this because I want to use export default but "as" doesn't seem to work.

```
const fn1 = () => {};
const fn2 = () => {};

export default = {
  fn1 as function1,
  fn2 as function2,
} // -> not working
```

How can I do what I want?

Comment: I would consider `export default` in this case to be a strange choice. What's the reasoning for using that instead of named exports?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What follows `export default` should be an *expression* (not a `=`). So all you need to do after that is use the right syntax for a normal Javascript object:

```
export default {
  function1: fn1,
  function2: fn2,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that is a wrong syntax. Correct use would be without `'='` before `"{"`.

```
export default {
  fn1 as function1,
  fn2 as function2
}
```

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: The syntax in your answer is still wrong. Are you trying to export an object or are you suggesting to use named exports?